# Alchemy Logs for debugging issue

Tags: a4t

I'm currently trying to debug the installer issue I am having with version 0.8.2 of Alchemy4Tridion. My issue is that I can not uninstall Alchemy4Tridion program from my computer and when trying to resolve the issue I receive the Error 1001:

(An exception occurred while uninstalling. This exception will be ignored and the uninstall will continue. However, the application might not be fully uninstalled after the uninstall is complete. --> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

When trying to resolve and debug the issue, I tried to look for Alchemy debug level logs in my Windows file explorer. The only thing I see are my Alchemy logs, in the log folder, which contain logs of the plugins I have installed into my Tridion environment.
I wanted to know if users able to see debug level logs of 
Is there any place in the Alchemy logs that shows the debug level logs for users to understand what the issue is?

Answer (score 2):

Alchemy logs these things in the Windows Application Event logs.

Comment: Can you expand on what kind of logging statements you're able to see in these logs for future users? Are these from core Alchemy functionality, plugins, installers, etc?